# Do browsers like chrome and firefox support displaying srt subtitles in movies?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I have a web video player, and I was wondering if PC browsers support srt files, I have something like `movie1.mkv` and its srt file: `movie1.srt` Can I play the movie in chrome/firefox with its srt file displayed ?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement them using the `<track>` element that is supported in HTML5. You can do this by converting your .srt file into a WebVTT file and adding it to the `<track>` tag.

Comment: what about softsub, how do I show them in browsers like above ?. Softsubs are subtitles that are implemented in videos, they are not in srt formats. They become one with the videos.

Comment: with a softsub program, you are merging the .srt subtitle file into the video file for a NEW video file with the subtitles within the video. So, you would not have an .srt file playing in tandem with a .mp4 file. You would use a program that would give you a single, new, .mp4 file that has subtitles in it. Then you can implement that into a webpage and the subtitles will display because it is only a single .mp4 video. Make sense? :)

Answer (score -1):

Check out the "track" element for subtitles and captions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video

It uses a vtt format. There are converters to change srt to vtt. https://atelier.u-sub.net/srt2vtt/